# Mirror EC2 Instance with Windows from Ireland to Frankfurt

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon AWS Windows Server running (t2.micro), in Ireland.
I created a new Instance in Frankfurt (m3.xlarge), where I want to transfer the main boot volume from Ireland to. Thus, I

1. create a snapshot from the instance in Ireland
2. copy the snapshot to Frankfurt
3. create a volume from the snapshot
4. detach the main volume from the Frankfurt instance
5. attach the snapshot volume to the Frankfurt instance (/dev/sda1)
6. Try to connect with Remote Desktop to the instance (after restarting it, of course)

Still, I get an `Unable to connect to RDP server xx.xx.xx.xx`, while everything works fine when I attach the original volume instead of the irish one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new instance in Frankfurt, detaching volume and re-attaching the snapshot volume copied from Ireland, you need to create a image from the instance in Ireland, start a new instance in Frankfurt from the image you created, aws will do the reconfiguring of the instance for you.